# Selecting rows with constrained time-stamp differences (in seconds) in tables in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-timestamp

I have a table called visit_times in SQL like this

```
    name   time_stamp
    Allen  2015-02-13 07:10:54
    Allen  2015-02-13 07:10:58
    Allen  2015-02-13 07:11:02
    Mary   2015-02-17 10:45:33
    Mary   2015-02-17 10:45:39
    Mary   2015-02-17 10:45:43
    ...
```

I need to select names from "name" column for which **all** the row-consecutive differences (in second) in the "time_stamp" column equals a certain value. Using the LAG() command I have tried to code it up as follows

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT  name, 
          DATEDIFF(second, LAG(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_stamp), time_stamp) AS visit_gap 
  FROM customer_transactions
)
SELECT cte.name
FROM cte
GROUP BY cte.name
HAVING MIN(cte.visit_gap) = 10 AND MAX(cte.visit_gap) = 4;
```

I expect to get the result as follows:

```
---------
| name  |
---------
| Allen |
---------
```

But it outputs nothing! I get the error:   in the pre-written template: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

I am not sure how to fix this. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the unit of the "visit gap" supposed to be here?

Comment: Are you in MS SQL Server or Azure?

Comment: If so, what's your SQL Server version?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it is in seconds

Comment: @AminGheibi It is MS SQL Server

Comment: It gives you an error or the result is not what you expected? Can you post your expected output and what you get?

Comment: @AminGheibi it gives a syntax error (it says near line WHERE visit_gap = 4) while I expect a single name from "name" column to be output.

Comment: @AminGheibi The error I get says: Unknown column 'visit_gap' in 'where clause'

Comment: You just made this a lot more confusing. [1] This code does not produce an error, only a warning at most. [2] What is your intention with the grouping? Any data will _never_ have both a minimum of 10 _and_ a maximum of 4... [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3d2c704c5bc3558b211603846a6deced) with some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL queries are processed in a certain order (a quick search for "sql query order of operations" gave me this [nice result](https://learnsql.com/blog/sql-order-of-operations/)). The column alias `visit_gap` can only be reused starting from the `order by` clause. This explains your syntax error.

The usual solution would be to duplicate the `visit_gap` expression in the `where` clause giving you this:

```
SELECT  name, 
        time_stamp - LAG(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_stamp) AS visit_gap
FROM visit_times
WHERE time_stamp - LAG(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_stamp) = 4;
```

However, this will give you a new error that states that the `LAG()` function cannot appear in the `where` clause...

> Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

In order to separate the `LAG()` or `visit_gap` calculation and the filtering (`where` clause) you could use a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) (CTE). Also, use the `DATEDIFF()` function ([function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql)) to calculate the difference between dates.

```
with cte as
(
  SELECT  name, 
          datediff(second, LAG(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_stamp), time_stamp) AS visit_gap
  FROM visit_times
)
select cte.name,
       cte.visit_gap --> column alias is available now!
from cte;
```

Adding a filter in the where clause gives you your final result:

```
with cte as
(
  SELECT  name, 
          datediff(second, LAG(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_stamp), time_stamp) AS visit_gap
  FROM visit_times
)
select cte.name,
       cte.visit_gap --> column alias is available now!
from cte
where cte.visit_gap > 4;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82148d8d96ae140ad047b7405609c429) with all intermediate steps explained!

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed explanation. In using datediff function I get this error:    Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

Comment: I tried using     time_stamp - LAG(time_stamp) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY time_stamp) AS visit_gap    instead of datediff() function. This would only work on the time differences that do not involve two consecutive minutes, i.e., it cannot capture the qualified time difference in seconds on a case like this   1:59 -> 2:03   which differs by 4 seconds by the minutes are switching

Comment: Look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) I linked to in my answer. The `datediff()` function takes 3 arguments (multiple examples available in the documentation). Also, the `datediff()` function with argument `second` handles different minutes just fine: [examples](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=67d015af67cb7cae7b0406f1c07e9049&hide=62).

Comment: I used TIMESTAMPDIFF() instead of datediff() and it worked!